# simple-jdin/jdbc.properties is ignored in pentaho-server 8.2

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

If we need to perform queries in pentaho data integration (IDE), we need to add manually the datasource in simple-jdin/jdbc.properties

```
MyDatabase/type=javax.sql.DataSource
MyDatabase/driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
MyDatabase/url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/sampledata
MyDatabase/user=pentaho_admin
MyDatabase/password=password
```

This works as expected in the ide known as pentaho data integration, spoon or kettle.

But, the same in pentaho server 8.2 does not works.

## Steps to reproduce the error

- deploy or upload the transformation(.ktr) in the pentaho-server 8.2
- add manually the datasource in the server /../pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/simple-jndi/jdbc.properties
- executed the transformation using pentaho server web console : run in background or schedule options
- error: datasource not found

## Alternative

- Create the datasource manually using web console of pentaho server instead of manually modification of file : /../pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/simple-jndi/jdbc.properties

## Question

- simple-jndi/jdbc.properties works in server or is just for development purposes (pdi)?

Answer (score 0):

are the settings available in jdbc.properties file on server can you verify the same by referring to  the pentaho data integrator > simple-jndi folder.
also are you able to connect to the database from the server may be using a database client to confirm.

NOTE:whenever you work with databases make sure you relevant library files to connect to the respective database.

Comment: pentaho data integrator has its jdbc.properties and pentaho server has another jdbc.properties. These files are identical. Database works very well, as I said : transformation works in pdi, but not in server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, I was not able to make the server pick JNDI connection definitions from the `simple-jndi/jdbc.properties` file when the Pentaho Server was running with Tomcat.

I was only able to use JNDI on the Pentaho Server by defining [JNDI Datasources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) in the Tomcat configuration files.